# Collect all records from database and checked the exist

Tags: arrays, object, yii, checked

I'm working in Yii framework and i have one problem .
I have one table with amenities and i want to find it all.

$amenities = RoomTypeAmenity::model()->findAll();
This command work fine .

Then i want to find what amenities have this room and type 
$amenities_room = RoomTypeAmenity::model()->with('idRoomTypeAmenity')->findAll();
And this command work fine . But when print the amenities i want to checked the exist amenities .

```
    foreach ($amenities as $amenity) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>">
        <label class="css-label" for="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>"><?php echo $amenity->name; ?></label>

        <?php  }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if else` condition inside `for-loop`. Check whether current amenity_room exists for current amenity. If exits, then `checked` the `checkbox`.

```
foreach ($amenities as $amenity) { ?>
     if($amenity->id_room_type_amenity!=null){
         <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>" checked>
         <label class="css-label" for="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>"><?php echo $amenity->name; ?></label>
     } else {
         <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>">
         <label class="css-label" for="facility_<?php echo $amenity->id_room_type_amenity; ?>"><?php echo $amenity->name; ?></label>
     }

<?php  }?>
```

Hope this helps!